# Junit doesn't read static field

Tags: java, javafx, junit

i have this class with this static field

```
public class Parameters {

    public Parameters()
    {   
    }
    
    public static Image img = new Image(new File("myImage.png").toURI().toString());

}
```

and the junit class

```
import Parameters.*;

@Test
    void test() {
    Image img = Parameters.img; //error here 

}
```

the problem is that when i debug Parameters.img is null, i get the error
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError,
i don't know how to fix it, to read that image from the test

also to mention the Image class is from javafx.

Comment: Please add the error stack trace. It is useful to better understand your problem. I'd say that there's an error while you try to create the img static field in Paramaeters class. But we need more details.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using a framework such as [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX) to test your JavaFX application code.  That framework will ensure that the JavaFX runtime is correctly started or shutdown before you execute the body of your test code which makes use of the JavaFX runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code style is not a good idea.

Your Parameters class includes static initialization - anytime any code so much as looks in the general direction of Parameters, the JVM realizes that Parameters hasn't been loaded yet, so the JVM goes out and loads it; as part of that job, the code `new Image(new File("myImage.png").toURI().toString())` runs, and that throws an exception.

Exceptions in initializers are annoying for a number of reasons, thus leading to the conclusion: **Do not** put code that is somewhat likely to error in initializers.

A better strategy would be to make a method instead:

```
private static Image getMyImage() {
    return new Image(...);
}
```

or possibly involve a cache of some sort (first time load it, future times just return the cached object). Now the exception is thrown 'during normal program flow' (as part of invoking a method, not as part of loading a class).

More generally, this concept doesn't work with File at all, you don't want images as separate files, they are resources and should be in the same place your class files are, even (especially!) if your class files are in a jar file. That involves: `new Image(Parameters.class.getResource("myImage.png"))`. This tells the JVM to look in the same place Parameters.class is at.

This code should *still* be in a method and not in a static field init like this.

Comment: i tried using the static method instead, but i still get an error "NoclassDefFoundError"

Comment: the problem is that i reuse the same images in diffrent classes, and i cannot create a new image every time i need the specific image, to be specific i put the same image reference in more imageview classes, if i would create a new image for everytime i reuse it would overload

Comment: This also just smacks of "Global data", which is generally problematic in OOP. Consider creating the Image in, perhaps, the `start()` method and just passing it to wherever it's needed. If that becomes cumbersome, consider using a dependency injection framework and injecting the image where it's needed.

Comment: @andrew21 *"[If] i put the same image reference in more imageview classes, if i would create a new image for everytime i reuse it"*. This is not true. If the different references all refer to the same instance, it would only be loaded once.

Comment: I think the advice in this answer is especially relevant for JavaFX code.  The JavaFX runtime has a lifecycle (see the [`Application`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) and [`Platform`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#startup(java.lang.Runnable)) classes).  When you execute code in static initializers you run the risk of trying to perform operations which would attempt to use the JavaFX runtime at a point when that runtime has not been initialized.